# Cannot find name 'KeyboardEvent'

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 2 (v2.4), created with Angular CLI RC0, and editing with VS Code and am getting the following following error on the `KeyboardEvent` type: **Cannot find name 'KeyboardEvent'**

```
eventHandler(event: KeyboardEvent) {
  // ...
}
```

Am I missing a typing or something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Install Typescript**

use `npm install --save-dev typescript` to install typescript to your local environment.
you will find KeyboardEvent defined at node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts

**Add libs for tsconfig.json**

```
"lib": ["dom"]
```

After the above steps, reopen the typescript source.

Comment: Thanks for that! Where do I include the definition file once I've done the npm install in the Angular 2 project?

Comment: use command(windows) or terminal(macOS) and the "npm install" command to install once again.This will update your denpendencies that you have installed.

Comment: I've done that and it's added the required files. Now I'm stuck with an ugly looking include `/// <reference path="../../../../node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.d.ts" />`. Is there any other way?

Comment: @RichardUeckermann what IDE are you using? basically this libarary is no need to include.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are working with vanilla typescript locally add , I have faced this problem when I tried to use the google/gts template

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["dom"],
      .
      .
      . 
  },
```

in tsconfig.json